# Git SVN rebase failed without meaningful error

Tags: git, git-svn

The following has been happening to me recently.

I am using git svn on a branch on Linux (RHEL). I commit some local changes and then try to git svn rebase. The error message is follows:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: My Commit Message
Patch failed at 0001 My Commit Message

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".

rebase refs/remotes/trunk: command returned error: 1
```

Aborting works fine. There isn't anything in this I know how to work off of. Any tips?

Thanks for taking a look,

Teddy

**Update**

The way I have things set up is a main git-svn repository I work off of with 3 git-svn repositories in subdirectories for svn externals. SVN trunk head seemed to be a checkin to one of these externals. Is anyone able to shed some light on whether this might cause this issue to manifest?

Answer (score 1):

"Patch failed" is a meaningful error. Basically, it means that the changes you've made to your branch do not cleanly apply to the trunk. Try `git status` to see where the conflict is, resolve it and do the `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: git status tells me I'm not on a branch (I imagine because I am in the middle of rebasing?) and lists some untracked files that I'm OK with being untracked. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What's interesting is that I found out I can do git rebase \`git svn find-rev rMAXREV\` fine without any conflicts, and then git svn rebase just says I'm up to date. I can't and haven't dcommitted yet.

Comment: I'd expect `git status` to show conflicts, though I do not remember exactly how they're shown… not as untracked files, I'd guess…

Comment: Yeah, this is extremely confusing for me. Thanks for taking time to look at this. Let me know if something occurs to you.

Comment: Well, provided you have refs to anchor your branches you may just experiment by applying (cherry-picking) the failing patch to the trunk (just create a new branch and don't worry). Maybe it will give you some idea. I haven't used `git svn` myself for a bit over a year now…

Comment: @TNi: Yes, you're not on a branch because you're in the middle of rebasing. `git status` should tell you which files are conflicted and how to resolve the conflicts; once that's done you should be able to use `git rebase --continue` to complete the `git svn rebase`.